# Relate Product quantity to Stock - Custom module - OpenErp

Tags: python, module, odoo, product

I got a module which uses items, products, currencies, uom's etc.

I need that when i ask a requisition, or  purchase a product in the openerp's database, it automatically discharges the quantity off the database of the system.

I saw in 'product.product' that there is some function/fields called

```
_product_qty_available
_product_virtual_available
_product_outgoing_qty
_product_incoming_qty
```

Should i inherit these functions to manage the products in my module, and get them updated in the system like a requisition or purchase order?

The code of my module.py

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
from osv import osv, fields
from openerp.tools import DEFAULT_SERVER_DATE_FORMAT, DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT, DATETIME_FORMATS_MAP
import openerp.addons.decimal_precision as dp
from openerp.tools.translate import _

class certificados(osv.osv):

_name = 'certificados.certificados'
_description="Certificados de No Produccion"

_columns = {
            'Registro_Numero' : fields.integer('Registro Numero'),
            'Fecha_de_Emision': fields.date('Fecha de Emision', required=True, select=True),
            'Fecha_de_Solicitud': fields.date('Fecha de Solicitud', required=True, select=True),
            'Fecha_del_Documento': fields.date('Fecha del Documento', required=True, select=True),
            'Vigencia' : fields.integer('Vigencia'), 'cert_ids' : fields.one2many('certificados.line','requisicion_id','Items del Certificado'),
            'descripcion' : fields.text('Descripcion'),
            'notas' : fields.text('Notas'),
            }


class certificados_line(osv.osv):

_name = "certificados.line"
_description="Certificados No Produccion"
_inherit = ['mail.thread', 'ir.needaction_mixin']

_columns = {
    'Item' : fields.integer('Item'),
    'Codigo_Arancelario' : fields.integer('Codigo Arancelario'),
    'product_id' : fields.many2one('product.product', 'Material'),
    'Descripcion_Arancelaria' : fields.char('Descripcion Arancelaria', size=42, required = True, translate = True), 
    'Especificaciones_Tecnicas' : fields.char('Especificaciones Tecnicas', size=60, required = True, translate = True), 
    'Cantidad' : fields.float('Cantidad'), 'Unidad_de_Medida': fields.many2one('product.uom', 'Unidad de Medida'),
    'Precio_Unitario_Declarado' : fields.float('Precio Unitario Declarado'), 'Moneda' : fields.many2one('res.currency', 'Moneda'),
    'Valor_En_Divisas' : fields.float('Valor En Divisas'),
    'requisicion_id' : fields.many2one('certificados.certificados', 'Certificados de No Produccion', ondelete='cascade'),
    'Cantidad_Consumida' : fields.float('Cantidad Consumida'), 'Cantidad_Disponible' : fields.float('Cantidad Disponible'),

}
certificados_line()
```

I hope i explained myself, thanks in advance.

Comment: Would you please provide more information?

Comment: This module as you can see loads a 'product.product' object, as it is  product_id in certificados.line, So i need a method to update the product database in the stock automatically from this custom module, like if i buy a product, from the data i have in this module, it automatically updates the stock in openerp, but i'm not sure what i have to inherit to achieve this.

Comment: As you inherit product_id in your module, when you going to sale then it automatically decrease your stock and purchase then increase stock, when you install stock module then it start working

Comment: Yes, well, product_id inherits the product itself, now, the quantity is an integer type field, it would do what i'm looking for? or should i use for 'quantity' another inherited object from product.product?

Comment: 'quantity' is float, sorry, but the question stands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use product_id in your module, you just inherit it by many2one. Stock of that product will automatically maintain by OpenERP. If you will sell it, stock of that product will be decrease and if you will purchase it, stock of that product will be increase. You can also set initial stock of that product as per your need.